# HA Swarm cluster with docker-machine

Tags: docker, high-availability, docker-machine

I have a Swarm cluster which currently only has a single master. So far the whole thing has been deployed using `docker-machine`. I have another node  that I would like to use as another master.

When I use the following command I essentially create another cluster:

`docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ip-address=<master1-ip> \
    --generic-ssh-key /root/.ssh/id_rsa --swarm --swarm-master \
    --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip master0):8500" \
    --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip master0):8500" \
    --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376" master1`

Is actually possible to create a second master with machine?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. `--swarm-discovery` was not pointing to the right node :-( Needs to point to the existing master.